# Python Erro containing main

Tags: python

hi everyone i am trying to run the below attached piece of code but it is giving me the error of main is not defined although i have tried to wrap it in both single and double quotes as well...

```
import time
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try: 
        while True:
            print("##########################################################################################")
            
            start_time = time.perf_counter()
            logger.warning("STARTING CALCULATIONS...")
            
            main()
            
            end_time= time.perf_counter()
            logger.warning(f"FINISHED CALCULATIONS AFTER {end_time - start_time} seconds.")
            print("##########################################################################################")
            print("Press ctrl+c to terminate process.")
            
            time.sleep(set_loop_time)
            
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acXnm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUsFL.png)

Comment: Please copy and paste the code into the question so we can run it (see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))

Comment: this is giving an error because the main function is not defined anywhere in you code in order to call it you've to define it first

Comment: Please post the error as text not as image. This makes is more accessible and future-proof.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a function, it is required to exist.

In line 12, you're trying to run a function named `main`. According to your code, you did not define said function. This is also stated by your programs error output.

How to fix: You need to create a function named `main`